# VBA Find First Empty Cell and Input Text

Tags: excel, vba

I publish a simple price list. Now I need to add 'notes' at the end, after the last entry. The cell with the note will rarely be the same since we are constantly adding and removing product. I would also like to merge all the cells in that row, so when I AutoFit the formatting will not be lost.

```
Sub Append Notes to last page()
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "*Logo Quantity - Some items may be combined. See Account Manager."
    ActiveCell.Resize(1, 20).MergeCells
End Sub
```

I expected this to just go to the end of the pricelist and find the first blank cell in column A and paste the text, then merge the row of cells.

I appreciate any insight or assistance.

Comment: and what is it doing instead?  To start with, the name of a `Sub` cannot include spaces.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, sorry, I copied my note, not the actual Sub. It is not doing anything. No error, or stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use spaces in the Sub name.
Use it without space or replace spaces with other valid character.

```
Sub AppendNotestolastpage()
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "*Logo Quantity - Some items may be combined. See Account Manager."
    ActiveCell.Resize(1, 20).Merge
End Sub
```

Try the above code. I have changed "ActiveCell.Resize(1, 20).Merge" line only.

Comment: THAT IS IT. Thank you so much.